# BackboneJS - Multiple Collections in one view

Tags: json, backbone.js

I have a leftMenu section where I want to display 4 menus which are categorized by each subject. Every menu is a list and I want them to be displayed in the same View. I created 4 JSON files and to each one of them a Collection and a Model.

Usually i do it like this, first i define in router

```
this.mainMenuCollection = new MainMenuCollection();
this.mainMenuView = new MainMenuView({el:'#nav', collection:this.mainMenuCollection});
```

So, now I have these 4 collections defined in the router which I want in one view:

```
this.allcategoryMenuCollection = new AllCategoryMenuCollection();
this.natcategoryMenuCollection = new NatCategoryMenuCollection();
this.intcategoryMenuCollection = new IntCategoryMenuCollection();
this.topcategoryMenuCollection = new TopCategoryMenuCollection();
```

usually i render the collection in the View like this:

```
$(this.el).html(this.template({mainmenu:this.collection.toJSON()}));
```

Please help

Comment: Are these static JSON files?  If so, is there a reason why you don't combine them into one single model?  On a more theoretical note, models are used to reflect the state of your application.  They are designed to store data about the user or application.  It doesn't really make sense to use them to store static menu links.

Answer (score 3):

Send in the collections as an object when you create your view:

```
this.mainView = new MainView({
  el:'#nav'
});
this.mainView.collections = {
    allcategoryMenuCollection: this.allcategoryMenuCollection
    natcategoryMenuCollection: this.natcategoryMenuCollection
    intcategoryMenuCollection: this.intcategoryMenuCollection
    topcategoryMenuCollection: this.topcategoryMenuCollection
  }
```

Access your collections inside the view by calling `this.collections.collectionName`

Comment: You will only have access to `this.collections` if you set it in `initialize` by doing `this.collections = options.collections`, where `options` is the first argument in `initialize`.

Comment: @kalley, good catch. But they just changed that whole `options` thing in the newest release of Backbone. Even that won't work anymore. I will update my answer with a better solution.

Comment: Actually, that still will, but you won't have access on `this.options.collections` unless you set an `options` property on the view in `initialize`

Comment: Hmm ok in my View i have now `$(this.el).html(this.template({categoryInt:this.collections.intcategoryMenuCollection.toJSON()}));` in the render function and the `initialize: function (options) {this.collections = options.collections;},` - it says "this.collections is undefined" ?? - does that have to do with that I define the collections in the router (like mentioned above) and the View is an external file?

Comment: You hybridized my response and @kalley's response.  If you use my code you don't need to do anything in initialize, you can remove that function again. `this.collections` will not be available until after initialization.

Comment: @RustyToms well, something is going wrong... maybe because have a router.js and a leftmenu.js (view) and i define the collections in the router and do the `this.collections`-thing in the view?

Comment: I can't give you advice until I see what you have done with your code.  What error are you getting? Do you have an initialize function in your view? If so, what is the code?

Comment: @RustyToms I get the error "this.collections is undefined" and no, i dont have an initialize function, just render... I will update the code above

Comment: Okay, rollback that update so that the question looks like before, it will confuse people who look at this later. You cannot call `.render()` until after you have assigned `collections`. Remove that render and add `this.artistpageLeftMenuView.render();` after you assign the collections. Then you probably want to change the last three of your `.html()` to `.append()` in your render function, each `.html()` overwrites the last.

Comment: @RustyToms That did partially work, the view gets rendered and no errors in the console, just the collections are not getting loaded and the append apparently made, that the 4 lists are loaded four times, without the collections :-) But thanks for your help!

Comment: @SHT, I'm not going to go through your whole project here. This site's purpose is to create a resource that others can use to solve their problems by doing their own research. You need to put the question back to the way it was at first or I am going to downvote it because it is not helpful to anyone else who finds it in a search. The issue that should be addressed by this question is how to allow a view to have access to multiple collections.

Comment: ok, this is driving me crazy! I'll do it the complicated way and create a view for each single collection...

Comment: It's probably better to pass them in through the initializer .. especially if you need the data to be fetched before render. You can _.pick individual options from your options and apply them to your object automagically:

i.e. _.extend(this, _.pick(options, 'vent', 'mode'));

Answer (score 3):

This may not seem like a semantically accurate way to do it, but to take advantage of backbone automatically assigning the `model` and `collection` properties in `options`, I do this:

```
var view = new MyView({
  collection: {
    comments: new CommentsCollection(),
    images: new ImagesCollection()
  }
});
```

Works for me. Otherwise you have to put a line in the `initialize` function to extend `this`, or use a base class. Personally I find this more elegant, even if it's missing a couple of pluralised properties.

Then, later on, you can use `this.collection.comments.toJSON()` for your template properties.

Comment: hey can you explain how did you then access these collections in template file?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with housing a number of sub-views within an outer view. Your outer view could be something as simple as this. If you need to wait for all of your collections to be fetched before you render you could try:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize : function (options) {
    var done, collections = options.collections;

    done = _.invoke(collections, 'fetch');
    $.when.apply($, done).done(this.onDataReady);
  },

  onDataReady : function () {
    // Make a second pass at render after setting the flag.
    this.ready = true;
    this.render();
  },

  render : function () {
    if(this.ready === true) {
       // Now render the whole lot.
    } else {
       // Any non-data depending rendering.
    }
  }
});
```

Then you can either initialize the outer view and pass an array of collections in:

```
var view = new MyView({
   collections: [...]
});
```

If you don't need all the collections to have fetched their data before hand it's even simpler. Just pass in the collections array and set them up as you need:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function (options) {  
        this.collectionA = options.collections[0];
    },

    render : function () {

    }
});
```